# Nancy and WebAPI in OWIN self host conflicting routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, nancy

I'm doing some work with OWIN for the first time and am trying to set things up so that I can leverage Web API with attributed routing for backend services and I'd like to use Nancy as a simple file server to serve up my angular SPA code.

My OWIN startup code:

```
public class Startup : IOwinAppBuilder
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        //FormatterConfig.ConfigureFormatters(config.Formatters);

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        //appBuilder.UseNancy();
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

I have a Test controller set up with some endpoints appropriately decorated for attribute routing. At this point running the app and attempting to hit one of those endpoints returns the expected results.

I then tried to add Nancy to the equation. I added a single Nancy Module with the intention that it would serve up the angular content:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => View["home"];
    }
}
```

Uncommenting the `appBuilder.UseNancy()` line in the Startup and running the server works perfect to get the home view. However, now when I attempt to hit one of the API endpoints, Nancy seems to be kicking in and handling the request and returning me a 404 page instead of the API result. Is there a way to make Nancy and Web API play nicely together such that their routes will not conflict like this?

Comment: Why do you need 2 frameworks to solve 1 problem. Use Nancy OR use Web API.

Answer (score 3):

Did you test the PerformPassThrough or PassThroughWhenStatusCodesAre in UseNancy() method?

It is documented in Conditional pass-through section of Hosting nancy with owin. ( https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin#conditional-pass-through )

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of those overloads but they look really promising. I'll give things a try tomorrow and mark this as the answer if it works out. Thanks :D